# React Hooks - setting object not re-rendering the component's data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, use-effect

I am using React useState to declare my object:

```
    const [results, setResults] = useState();
  console.log(results);
```

In same file I am returning React component and I am passing it some props:

```
 <Table
          data={results ? results.Companies : []}
          setData={(newArr) => {
            let newResults = results;
            newResults.Companies = newArr.slice(0);
            console.log(newResults);
            return setResults(newResults);
          }}
        />
```

P.S.: Keep in mind that I am passing to **data** only **results.Companies** which is *array*.

In this **Table** component I am changing the **results.Companies** property:

```
props.setData(arr);
```

So when it triggers function in **Table** component:

```
setData={(newArr) => {
                let newResults = results; // I am assigning to newResults current result state
                newResults.Companies = newArr.slice(0); // I am replacing newResults.Companies with new array I want to pass
                console.log(newResults); // HERE is the desired results output
                return setResults(newResults);
              }}
```

The **newResults** variable is exactly the result I want to be passed to setResutlts. But this setting does not trigger re-rendering and this **console.log(results)** for example is not called. 
Why it is not trigger after I am passing new value to **setResults()**

Comment: can you make a codesandbox?

Comment: @RedBaron It's kind of complicated items and code. I am fetching initial results from API where I am using token and so on...

Comment: but if you make a simplified version with mocked data then it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `setData` is a callback used by `Table`.

You have [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#:~:text=A%20closure%20is%20the%20combination,scope%20from%20an%20inner%20function.) on `results` **and** you mutate state which is [an anti-pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state).

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterward may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

Due closures you keep calling `setData` with the last value of `results` upon its initialization, and by mutating the state you actually don't update state as by how `setState` works.

After understanding what closures are, you should refactor the code to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

```
const setData = (newArr) => {
  setResults((prev) => {
    let newResults = {...prev, Companies: newArr.slice(0)};
    return newResults;
  });
}
<Table setData={setData}/>
```